# Why doesn't the regular expression '.+\s.+\n' get the expected list of strings?

Tags: python, regex

The regular expression '.+\s.+\n' matches 'China Beijing\nUS Washington\n' without getting the expected list of strings

Match the strings with regular expression

```
import re
a = re.compile(r'.+\s.+\n')
str1 = 'China Beijing\nUS Washington\n'
b = a.findall(str1)
print(b)
```

I want to output `['China Beijing\n', 'US Washington\n']`, But the actual output ['China Beijing\nUS Washington\n']，However, when I matched with '. . \n', I got ['China Beijing\n', 'US Washington\n'].why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Because the pattern `.+\s.+\n` matches your whole string. Try a more selective pattern.

Comment: Use `[^\n]+` if that satisfies your requirements

Comment: To be more precise `.` after `\s` matches everything including `\n` just before `US`.

Comment: `\s` matches newlines. Just `s.splitlines()` should do. Or `re.split(r'(?<=\n)', s)` will work in Python 3.7+. But you may also use `re.findall(r'.*\n', s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non greedy operator : `.*?`

```
import re
a = re.compile(r'.*?\s.*?\n')
str1 = 'China Beijing\nUS Washington\n'
b = a.findall(str1)
print(b)
```

Or a more selective patterns with `\w` or `[A-z]+` instead of `.`

```
import re
a = re.compile(r'\w+\s\w+\n')
str1 = 'China Beijing\nUS Washington\n'
b = a.findall(str1)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are using contains the `\s` special sequence. This sequence matches also \n as described in python's re documentation.
Therefore it will greedily match the largest string which corresponds to matching `China Beijing\nUS Washington\n`

> When the UNICODE flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace
>   character, this is equivalent to the set [ \t\n\r\f\v]. The LOCALE
>   flag has no extra effect on matching of the space. If UNICODE is set,
>   this will match the characters [ \t\n\r\f\v] plus whatever is
>   classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

**Solution**

Use the following regex:

```
[A-z]+\s[A-z]+\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to filter out `\n` as well.

```
>>> s = "China Beijing\nUS Washington\n"
>>> re.findall(r'\S+\s+\S+',s)
['China Beijing', 'US Washington']
```